# Some main commands not found in MSYS2 after update-core

Tags: windows, bash, msys2

## Issue

Some main commands not found in MSYS2 after `update-core`.

## Environment

- Windows 8.1 64bit
- msys2-x86_64-20150916

## Detail

I introduced MSYS2 to my computer and performed update-core. However, after the update, when I type `pacman` or `update-core`, the terminal says `bash: pacman: command not found`. I rebooted MSYS2 and tried the same process but the result was the same. I re-installed MSYS2 and tried the same process but the result was the same. I'd like to get things right but don't know how.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: note the low number of followers for the msys* and mingw* tags here on S.O. You may be better help on the MSYS mailing lists. MSYS2 seems to be ontopic also. I use http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/MinGW-MSYS-f26539.html when I have a mingw/msys problem and find it very easy to use. Good luck.

Comment: What happens if you type `/usr/bin/pacman`?   What about `ls /usr/bin` ?  What about `echo $PATH`?  Is there anything unusual at all in the output of the update-core script?

Comment: The MSYS2 mailing list is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/mailman/msys2-users/ ; MSYS is different from MSYS2.

Comment: @DavidGrayson : Thanks for the good ideas and clarification on resources. Hopefully there is a better interface to browsing that group that sourceforge (IHMO ;-) ) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments.

Comment: > David Grayson `ls /usr/bin` gave me a list of various commands. `/usr/bin/pacman` yielded `error: no operation specified (use -h for help)`. Wow, it worked! Then I added `D:\msys64\usr` to PATH variable and everything seems to work fine now. Thank you!

Comment: FYI `update-core` was deprecated sometime in early 2016. Only need to run `pacman -Su` in future.

Answer (score 8):

`update-core` is deprecated; its functionality is now handled by pacman; run `pacman -Syuu`.

Answer (score 3):

Had the problem twice with two different Win10 VMs in a matter of days. For me, the manifestation was "diff: command not found". No obvious change in $PATH. C:\msys64\usr\bin no longer has diff in it.

Answer (score 3):

For me running: `pacman -S openssh` solved it (found it [here](https://www.booleanworld.com/get-unix-linux-environment-windows-msys2/))

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question I just had the same problem so figured I'd share my experience.  After installing [msys2-x86_64-20240113](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/tag/2024-01-13) on Windows 10 I could not run any commands without specifying the full path, and even then I still could not install any packages.

As suggested by the user ["stumpedatwork" over at GitHub](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2933#issuecomment-1461479234) the solution turned out to be changing the ownership of the install directory and child objects to my user, and then to grant my user full control.

##### Advanced Security Settings

[image: Advanced Security Settings]

##### Installation folder properties

[image: Installation folder properties]

I can now happily run commands and install packages.  I wasn't paying attention when I installed MSYS2 but I think the installer asked for elevated permissions which explains how the problem occurred.